# QGIS crashed when using labelling function

Tags: qgis, labeling

I am using QGIS 2.18.2 on a MAC OS Sierra.

Every time I try to "show labels for this layer" in the layer styling window, my program crashes as soon as I define the layer (by selecting "label with"). I see from a previous post that someone else had this same problem with an earlier version of QGIS, but that problem went unresolved in the comment string. Wondering if a solution has been found yet?

Comment: If the crash is reproducible, this should be a bug report rather than a question on StackExchange.

Comment: Try to update QGIS. It is now 2.18.9, and it may solve the problem.